# Partition array into N random chunks of different sizes with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, random

With `numpy.array_splits`, you can split an array into equal size chunks. Is there a way to split it into chunks based on a list?

How do I split this array into 4 chunks, with each chunk determined by the size of the chunk given in `chunk_size`, and consisting of random values from the array?

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(13)
a = np.arange(20)
chunk_size = [10, 5, 3, 2]
dist = [np.random.choice(a, c) for c in chunk_size]
print(dist)
```

but I get multiple duplications, as expected:

```
[array([18, 16, 10, 16,  6,  2, 12,  3,  2, 14]),
 array([ 5, 13, 10,  9, 11]), array([ 2,  0, 19]), array([19, 11])]
```

For example,

- 16 is contained twice in the first chunks
- 10 is contained in the first and second chunk

With `np.split`, this is the answer I get:

```
>>> for s in np.split(a, chunk_size):
...     print(s.shape)
...
(10,)
(0,)
(0,)
(0,)
(18,)
```

With `np.random.choice` and `replace=False`, still gives duplicate elements:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(13)
a = np.arange(20)
chunk_size = [10, 5, 3, 2]
dist = [np.random.choice(a, c, replace=False) for c in chunk_size]
print(dist)
```

While each chunk now does not contain duplicates, it does not prevent that, for example, 7 is contained in both the first and second chunk:

```
[array([11, 12,  0,  1,  8,  5,  7, 15, 14, 13]),
 array([16,  7, 13,  9, 19]), array([1, 4, 2]), array([15, 12])]
```

Comment: Why did you use `np.random`? Do you want to get contiguous chunks or random elements from the original array?

Comment: random elements, even np.split gives contingous chunks :-(

Comment: Use  `replace=False` with it.

Comment: @Divakar: it is different iterations of the for loop, and thus will be replaced.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `thus will be replaced`. You also said `but I get multiple duplications`, so it sounded like you are looking to get unique elements, hence suggested `replace=False`. Did you try out with it?

Comment: I do find duplicate elements with replace=False. I'm trying to make a MWE

Comment: @Divakar: provided an MWE.

Comment: At `dist = [np.random.choice(a,_, replace=False) for _ in chunk_size]`, use `dist` instead of `a` for the next iteration. So, you need to store `dist` from previous iteration and use it for the current iteration replacing `a`.

Comment: @Divakar: if you put that as the answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Would encourage you to put together those and post your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to ensure that every element of `a` is contained in exactly one chunk would be to create a random permutation of `a` first and then split it with `np.split`.

In order to get an array of splitting indices for `np.split` from `chunk_size` you can use `np.cumsum`.

#### Example

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.random.seed(13)
>>> a = np.arange(20)
>>> b = np.random.permutation(a)
>>> b
array([11, 12,  0,  1,  8,  5,  7, 15, 14, 13,
        3, 17,  9,  4,  2,  6, 19, 10, 16, 18])

>>> chunk_size = [10, 5, 3, 2]
>>> np.cumsum(chunk_size)
array([10, 15, 18, 20])

>>> np.split(b, np.cumsum(chunk_size))
[array([11, 12,  0,  1,  8,  5,  7, 15, 14, 13]),
 array([ 3, 17,  9,  4,  2]), array([ 6, 19, 10]), array([16, 18]),
 array([], dtype=int64)]
```

You could avoid the trailing empty array by omitting the last value in `chunk_size`, as it is implied by the size of `a` and the sum of the previous values:

```
>>> np.split(b, np.cumsum(chunk_size[:-1]))  # [10, 5, 3] -- 2 is implied
[array([11, 12,  0,  1,  8,  5,  7, 15, 14, 13]),
 array([ 3, 17,  9,  4,  2]), array([ 6, 19, 10]), array([16, 18])]
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar)

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(13)
dist = np.arange(0, 3286, 1)
chunk_size = [975, 708, 515, 343, 269, 228, 77, 57, 42, 33, 11, 9, 7, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
dist = [np.random.choice(dist,_, replace=False) for _ in chunk_size]
```

Comment: @mkrieger1: I do not understand what I am missing then. Could you help me out?

Comment: Actually, if I think again about the advice given, I don't think it would work as expected.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: I think the idea was to remove the elements that were picked for one chunk from the array so that they can't be duplicated in the following chunks. But for that you would have to use the *remaining* items as input for the next iteration, not those that were picked. I'm not sure how I can explain it better, because I don't know what exactly is unclear to you.

Comment: Maybe an example helps: Suppose the array is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] initially, and [2, 3] are picked for the first chunk. Then for the next iteration you would have to use the remaining items [1, 4, 5] as input to pick from. But the suggestion would have meant to use [2, 3] as input to pick from again.